# When I try to browse for a .xslx file a new Excel document opens

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt5, xlrd

I'm currently working on a GUI with PyQt5.
I am using the menu bar to load a file, when i click it the program calls this function:

```
   def getxlsbase(self):
        filePath_base, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Select file', './', 'Excel Files (*.xls *.xlsx)')
        base = xlrd.open_workbook(filePath_base)
        hoja_base = base.sheet_by_index(0)
        num_row = hoja_base.nrows
        num_col = hoja_base.ncols
```

When the browse window opens and I select the file, a blank Excel document opens, how can I avoid this?

EDIT:
I tried this method but I still have this issue, it only happens with excel docs. I am using Spyder3

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(filepath)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you provided works correctly.

```
import sys
import xlrd
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QAxContainer import QAxWidget

class AxWidget(QWidget):    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AxWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(800, 600)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.axWidget = QAxWidget(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.axWidget)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton('Select file', self, clicked=self.getxlsbase))

    def getxlsbase(self):
        filePath_base, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 
                                     'Select file', 
                                     './', 
                                     'Excel Files (*.xls *.xlsx)')
        print("filePath_base->", filePath_base)                             
        base = xlrd.open_workbook(filePath_base)
        print("base->", base) 
        hoja_base = base.sheet_by_index(0)
        print("hoja_base->", hoja_base)
        num_row = hoja_base.nrows
        print("num_row->", num_row)
        num_col = hoja_base.ncols
        print("num_col->", num_col)

        return self.openOffice(filePath_base, 'Excel.Application')

    def openOffice(self, path, app):
        self.axWidget.clear()
        if not self.axWidget.setControl(app):
            return QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Error', 'No installation  %s' % app)
        self.axWidget.dynamicCall(
            'SetVisible (bool Visible)', 'false')         
        self.axWidget.setProperty('DisplayAlerts', False)
        self.axWidget.setControl(path)        

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.axWidget.close()
        self.axWidget.clear()
        self.layout().removeWidget(self.axWidget)
        del self.axWidget
        super(AxWidget, self).closeEvent(event)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex  = AxWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, yes it works but my issue is that when I run it, a new Excel document opens on Excel I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood the question correctly, but if, like me, when you open an excel document, a window opens with a file selection, then you can do this:

```
    def get_path_excel_file(self):
        excel_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                                                   'Select file',
                                                   './',
                                                   'Excel Files (*.xls *.xlsx)')
        # assign a path to some element
        self.label_5.setText(f"{excel_path}")
    
    # we get the path from this element
    book = openpyxl.load_workbook(fr"{self.label_5.text()}")
```